# Comparing date string with NSPredicate

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I was wondering if there's anyway to filter a set using `NSPredicate` sorted by date, where the date is an `NSString` in `MMMM dd` (i.e. March 24) format (it's NOT an NSDate.).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are storing the date as a string in CoreData, the predicate is simple.

```
    NSPredicate* predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"theDate like %@", theDateString];
```

But I'm guessing that the date is stored as an NSDate object. Look into using [NSDateFormatter](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to convert your string to an NSDate.

```
NSDateFormatter* df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[df setDateFormat:@"MMMM dd"];
NSDate* theDate = [df dateFromString:theDateString];
NSPredicate* predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SomeDate >= %@", theDate];
```

Comment: It's stored as a string. The predicate you have wouldn't sort it, it would just find similiar matches. I don't have access to the string, because I'm setting the predicate on a core data fetch request..

Comment: As far as I know there is no way to do this in the predicate itself. I'm guessing you'll have to execute the fetch request and then sort the results manually based on the date string.

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert it to a NSDate first, which you can achieve with the predicateWithBlock function of NSPredicate.  Convert the object and test it in your predicate block.  I have never personally used it, so this answer is theoretical.

Answer (score 0):

Comparing NSDate or date in an NSArray with NSPredicate in Swift.

In Swift 2.1 or 2.0:

```
//format data
let Formata_Data = NSDateFormatter()
Formata_Data.calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
Formata_Data.dateFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy"
let _data_filtro = Formata_Data.stringFromDate(dias_filtros!)
let _data_hoje = Formata_Data.stringFromDate(NSDate())

let data_filtro_ns = Formata_Data.dateFromString(_data_filtro)

print("DATA.... \(_data_filtro)")

var predicate_Data = NSPredicate(block: { (data_string, Orcs) -> Bool in
    return data_filtro_ns?.earlierDate(Formata_Data.dateFromString(data_string) as! String)!) == data_filtro_ns
})
var array_filtro_dias = Orcamentos.filteredArrayUsingPredicate(predicate_Data)
Orcamentos = array_filtro_dias
```