# iOS: NSPredicate using date which is stored as string to compare

Tags: ios, swift, nspredicate

I have an NSDate attribute called startDate stored in the persistence store in string format like "2020-01-01T23:59:26+0530". I am trying to fetch all the data from the core data which falls before this date. But in my predicate I am not understanding how to form a format string. If the startDate was in Date format, then it would be something like below,
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "date < %@", startDate)
But my "date" is not Date instead its a string. I'm not sure how to convert the stored date in string format to just Date format only and apply that in Predicates for comparison. Any suggestions?

Comment: "I have an NSDate attribute called startDate stored in the persistence store in string format" Do you mean to say `date` rather than `startDate` here. `startDate` is a `Date` object right?

Comment: startDate is a string. Example, say current date is 2020-01-01T23:59:26+0530 then my startDate will be "2020-01-01T23:59:26+0530"

Answer (score 1):

If you need the time information as well when storing, then it is better to store it as a Date in CoreData because it is very hard and unnecessary coding to compare these.

If you only need date information, then when storing it to CoreData save it with **only Date** and compare it like this
[Comparing date string with NSPredicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9864630/comparing-date-string-with-nspredicate)